# How to convert a JSON to other JSON with special conditions

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I need a jolt-script to solve the problem. The idea were: one person has 2 or more numbers and the JSON data should be smaller. The JSON was flatted. I have an Input JSON like this.

```json
[
  {
    "person.first_name": "Peter",
    "person.last_name": "Thomson",
    "person.contact.phone": 123
  },
  {
    "person.first_name": "Peter",
    "person.last_name": "Thomson",
    "person.contact.phone": 987
  }
]
```

I need an output, that was unlatted:

```json
{
  "person": {
    "first_name": "Peter",
    "last_name": "Thomson",
    "contact": [
      {
        "phone": 123
      },
      {
        "phone": 987
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can principally use `"*.*"` vs. `"&(0,1).&(0,2)"` notations in order to group the elements due to the dot separated logic such as

```json
[
  { // take the key "person" to the outermost level
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*.*": "&(0,1).&1.&(0,2)"
      }
    }
  },
  { // group the objects by the first/last name values combination
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*name": "&2.@(1,first_name).@(1,last_name).&",
          "*.*": "&2.@(1,first_name).@(1,last_name).&(0,1)[&1].&(0,2)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the extra layers which nest by first/last name combination
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only single first and last names among the repeating ones
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*name": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the extra generated null values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]